# Error trying to use getElementsByName in order to choose multiple "placeholders" (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

This script of mine has a function, which is not working the way, I want it to. Take a look at the script, the function is called display_Value():

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <!--Scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    function noValue(id) {  
        var _value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        if (_value == "Skriv dit navn her") {
            document.getElementById(id).value='';
        }
    }

    function changeValue(id) {
        var _value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        if (_value == "") {
            document.getElementById(id).value='Skriv dit navn her';
        }
    }

    function display_Value() { 
        var val = document.getElementById("txt").value; 
        if (val != "Skriv dit navn her" && val != "") { 
            document.getElementsByName("placeholder").innerHTML = val; 
            document.getElementById("hidden").style.visibility="visible"; 
            destroy("destroy") 
        } 
    }

    function destroy(id) {
        var d = document.getElementById(id);
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }

    //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="destroy">
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="Skriv dit navn her" onFocus="noValue('txt')" onBlur="changeValue('txt')">
    <input type="button" onClick="display_Value()" value="Click me" />
    </div>

    <div id="hidden" style="visibility: hidden">
    <p>Hello. Your entered value is: <span name="placeholder"></span> and it is repeated below</p>
    <span name="placeholder"></span>
    <span name="placeholder"></span>
    </div>
```

The functions noValue() and changeValue() makes the original value disappear on focus and come back if the field is empty on blue. That part works. When the button is clicked, the value in the text box is supposed to be displayed in the `<span name="placeholder">`-tags. That's not happening. The hidden text which is hidden with `<div style="visibility:hidden">` is shown, as I want it to, but the value is not displayed. The form gets destroyed, just as I want to. Where have I made a mistake? :)

Ps.: If you are wondering what "Skriv dit navn her" means, it means "Write your name here" in danish.

### EDIT

I isolated parts of the code once again. I found out, that if I replace `getElementsByName("placeholder").innerHTML;` with `getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML;` and assigns the first `<span>` with and ID="placeholder" the value is displayed in that particular `<span>`.This is, however, not exactly what I wanted. I wanted the value to be displayed in all 3 of the placeholders - **how?**

### ANOTHER EDIT

I know it is possible to make this script work by assigning ID's to all of the placeholder; I'm not interested in that. I would like the function to display the value in all of the placeholders in as little text as possible and without repeating. I think this is called DRY / DIE :)

Comment: You could reduce your code by taking away the parts that work until you are left only with what doesn't work. 
Also, those comments around the javascript were obsolete a generation ago, I think

Comment: I know, I just do it to be sure :) and some weird people still turn JavaScript off manually :)

Comment: And in reply to the first thing, you wrote - I did that! I still could not find the source to where everything goes wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your display_Value function with this:

```
function display_Value() { 
    var val = document.getElementById("txt").value; 
    if (val != "Skriv dit navn her" && val != "") { 
        document.getElementsByName("placeholder").innerHTML = val; 
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.visibility="visible"; 
        destroy("destroy") 
    } 
}
```

You were taking the value of the placeholder, not a reference to it.  So the value wasn't going anywhere.  You need to assign it directly to the innerHTML of the placeholder.

Comment: try adding an alert after the `var val` line.. `alert(val);`.. is the value there?

Comment: Yes it is - this is very weird... I think the error might be in the getElementsByName("placeholder").innerHTML-line (check my update for "proof")

Comment: can you just use an ID.. i didn't even notice that.  Use a real ID and getElementByID

Comment: There are going to be a LOT of placeholders in this script and using ID's for them all will require a line of script each; I'd like to avoid that :) Do you know any ... ehm, what is it called? methods? for the document-object which returns multiple elements, just like the getElementsByName?

Comment: You want to take a string and put it in all of the placeholders simulataneously?... I'm not sure that makes sense.  You should check out jQuery, it's all I will use any more.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById returns just one element. An Id is supposed to be unique and not repeated over three tags.

So you could give your 3 spans 3 different ids, and set the value with 3 different lines of javascript code.

Or, you could use something like jQuery and give your spans a class:

```
<span class="placeholder" />
```

then in jquery jou can set the html of all spans at once:

```
$("span.placeholder").html(value);
```

Comment: I see pros and cons here. First of all: I'd like to avoid jquery. Second of all: there are going to be a lot of other placeholders in this script, so I would like to avoid using id's for them all; that would make the entire script somewhat unreadable...